# What is the best way to createAccountAction class in Liferay?

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, portlet, liferay-hook

I have a requirement to add the phone number field in create_account.jsp and then I need to save it in Database, for that I have created a hook for create Account-hook to add phone number field, and to Store phone number field in database I have created CreateAccount-ext, in the CreateAccount-ext I have directly copied the CreateAccountAction class and directly I modified that class.

Is it right way or do I need to extend my class to `CreateAccountAction` class? In `CreateAccountAction` class I have only modified the `addUser()` method only.

Comment: I've done some similar functionality with a _hook_ plugin. But if you use an _ext_ plugin you should try to _extend_ the original class and change the mapping in `ext-spring.xml`. Both ways make it easier to upgrade Liferay

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by creating the custom field for the user.

We can find some useful information in the below URL

https://www.liferay.com/web/meera.success/blog/-/blogs/working-with-liferay-custom-fields

Comment: links are subject to expire. Please add detailed information here itself

Comment: AFAIK, If we want add extra information to the existing liferay table , then we go for custom fields, but phone_table already exist by defualt, then i feel it is not a good approach.So I go with creating a field in create_account.jsp and CreateAccountAction-ext.

Comment: we can modify the CreateAccountAction class using hook. can i know any specific reason to modifying using the EXT?

Comment: no specific reason I dnt know how to do it, in the above scenario how do you create with hook , can you explain ?

Comment: Check this link for overriding the struts class https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/overriding-and-adding-struts-actions, Also this https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/overriding-a-portal-service-using-a-hook